# How to delete object in array of dictionaries using Key Value

Tags: swift

I have a array of dictionary like below:

```
    {
        "photo_id" = 255025344921316;
        "photo_url" = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p320x320/16143181_255025344921316_6580634265541865230_n.jpg?oh=4f6359dbc63241c9dfab29c8cfc570ef&oe=598E85AE";
    },

        {
        "photo_id" = 255024861588031;
        "photo_url" = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p75x225/16106022_255024861588031_911227627582642933_n.jpg?oh=0bc3fb9df0ccac44c9bd03e8ee1a407d&oe=597A199C";
    },

        {
        "photo_id" = 255024731588044;
        "photo_url" = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p320x320/16113986_255024731588044_6834401222098779590_n.jpg?oh=68b39d59c803e30754fa6aaab5ea3017&oe=598A3425";
    }
```

Now I want to delete the object that has a "photo_id : 255024731588044"

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the index of the dictionary that you want to delete using [`.index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688966-index) method  which performs performs [0(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

```
let index = array.index(where: { dictionary in
  guard let value = dictionary["photo_id"] as? Int
    else { return false }      
  return value == 255024731588044
})
```

You can delete it using the `index` value if it is not `nil`:

```
if let index = index {
  array.remove(at: index)
}
```

Here you can [download](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5pb7yzxqoj8ay2f/AACK4y7G9HcnrOmYsh1gqsA6a?dl=0) the playground.

Comment: really helpful answer

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the array is of type `[[String:Any]]` you can use filter on it to remove the specific value. Try doing this

```
let newArray = array.filter({ (dictionary) -> Bool in
    if let value = dictionary["photo_id"] as? Int{
        return value != 255024731588044
    }
    return false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let searchedPhotoID = 255024731588044
guard let index = arrayOfDict.index(where: {
    guard let photoID = $0["photo_id"] as? Int else { return false }
    return photoID == searchedPhotoID
}) else {
    return // photoID not found - handle somehow
}
arrayOfDict.remove(at: index)
```